# How to contain the Program Listing in the Appendix within the margin?

Tags: formatting, lyx, margins, lyx-layouts

[image: It currently looks like this exceeding the margin]

I have added the Code Listing using - Insert -> File -> Child Document
[image: This is how it looks like in the LyX doc. It is exceeding the page margin on the right.]

Comment: In the margin? Please explain...

Comment: @Werner I guess the question is how to keep it *out of* the margin? Is this a LyX question?

Comment: @Werner - I think it is keeping it out of the margin. That is, have the material stay inside the margin. Yes, it is related to LyX.

Comment: @cfr-Werner can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: One way would be to use a smaller font, another would be to break the lines.